# QGIS standalone plugin: Display a progress bar with a busy state

Tags: python, pyqgis, pyqt

I have a standalone QGIS plugin and to inidicate that the plugin is processing, I want to add a progress bar that indicates a busy state, but not showing the exact progress like in the picture below:

[image]

I use the following code:

```
def main(self):

    self.progress()

    ...some more code here...

    self.dlg.close()

def progress(self):

    self.dlg.progressBar.reset()
    self.dlg.progressBar.setRange(0,0)
```

So, the idea is the call the `def progress` at the beginning of my code and execute everything else afterwards and in the end the window closes. For the progress bar I used a minimum of 0, a maximum of 100 and a value of 0 in QT Designer, just to display an empty progress bar.

However, if I set the range to `(0,0)` (which should add a busy state to the progress bar), nothing happens. Any idea what I do wrong?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44187688/4699904

Comment: Thanks, that helped! So it seems Windows just freezes as long as the processing runs and I have to implement threading to solve this. I will try around and see if I can implement it.